# ORA-01861: literal does not match format string for case statement in oracle

Tags: oracle, date, datetime

please help me to correct this error I am getting this error continuously

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string for case statement in
>   oracle

```
SELECT activity_made,
       (CASE
            WHEN (TO_DATE(activity_made, 'DD-Mon-YYYY')) = TRUNC(SYSDATE) THEN TO_CHAR(activity_made, 'hh12:mi PM')
            WHEN TRUNC(TO_DATE(activity_made, 'MM-DD-YYYY')) BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'yy') AND TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) THEN TO_CHAR(activity_made, 'Mon dd')
            ELSE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(activity_made, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'mm/dd/yyyy')
        END)
           AS actmode
  FROM (SELECT (CASE
                    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
                            FROM sfa_activity sa
                           WHERE     sa.companyid = opp.companyid
                                 AND sa.opptyid = opp.opptyid
                                 AND sa.TYPE = 'NOTE') > 0
                    THEN
                        (SELECT NVL(MAX(TO_CHAR(sa.updat, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')), '0000/00/00 00:00:00')
                           FROM sfa_activity sa
                          WHERE     sa.companyid = opp.companyid
                                AND sa.opptyid = opp.opptyid
                                AND sa.TYPE = 'NOTE')
                    ELSE
                        (SELECT NVL(MAX(TO_CHAR(sa.updat, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')), '1001/01/01 01:01:01')
                           /*ELSE (SELECT (MAX(TO_CHAR(sa.updat,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')))*/
                           FROM sfa_activity sa
                          WHERE     sa.companyid = opp.companyid
                                AND sa.opptyid = opp.opptyid
                                AND sa.TYPE <> 'NOTE')
                END)
                   AS activity_made
          FROM sfa_opportunities opp
         WHERE companyid = 1192)
```

Comment: `0000/00/00 00:00:00` is not a valid date, you cannot convert it to a `DATE` value. It looks rather strange how you shuffle around with `TO_CHAR` and `TO_DATE` functions. Better run all logic with `DATE` values and set output format only once at the end.

Comment: Why are you storing dates in a `VARCHAR` column? That is a very bad idea to begin with

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `ACTIVITY_MADE` is in `yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss` format (as suggested by an inline view). If simplified, your query looks like

```
select to_date(activity_made, ...) --> should use the same format as below, in an inline view
from (select activity_made         -->TO_CHAR(sa.updat, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
      from sfa_opportunities)
```

So: if you used that format mask for `activity_made`, you should use it for `TO_CHAR` in the *main* `SELECT`. However, you used

- dd-mon-yyyy
- mm-dd-yyyy
- mm/dd/yyyy

Switch to `yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss` in `CASE`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to rewrite your query to something like the following:

```
SELECT sa.updat activity_made
     , CASE WHEN TRUNC(sa.updat) = TRUNC(SYSDATE) THEN TO_CHAR(sa.updat, 'hh12:mi PM')
            WHEN sa.updat > TRUNC(SYSDATE,'yy') THEN TO_CHAR(sa.updat, 'Mon dd')
            ELSE TO_CHAR(sa.updat, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
       END actmode
  FROM sfa_activity sa
 WHERE (sa.companyid, sa.opptyid) IN (SELECT opp.companyid, opp.opptyid 
                                        FROM sfa_opportunities opp
                                       WHERE companyid = 1192)
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN sa.TYPE = 'NOTE' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, sa.updat DESC
 FETCH first ROW ONLY
```

Your version has some drawbacks:

- unnecessary type conversions
- a lot of selects on the same table, that are not needed
- there might be also some performance issues

The handling when no activities are made should be made outside and not in the inner select. (Makes it easier to maintain.)

Answer (score 0):

> Thank you all, I got the solution by applying the case inside the activity_made

```
/* Formatted on 2018/09/10 14:15 (Formatter Plus v4.8.5) */
SELECT activity_made,
       (CASE
           WHEN activity_made = '0000/00/00 00:00:00'
              THEN NULL
           ELSE activity_made
        END
       ) AS actmode
  FROM (SELECT (CASE
                   WHEN (SELECT COUNT (*)
                           FROM sfa_activity sa
                          WHERE sa.companyid = opp.companyid
                            AND sa.opptyid = opp.opptyid
                            AND sa.TYPE = 'NOTE') > 0
                      THEN (SELECT NVL
                                      (MAX
                                          (TO_CHAR
                                              (CASE
                                                  WHEN TRUNC (sa.updat) =
                                                               TRUNC (SYSDATE)
                                                     THEN TO_CHAR
                                                                 (sa.updat,
                                                                  'hh12:mi PM'
                                                                 )
                                                  WHEN TRUNC (sa.updat)
                                                         BETWEEN TRUNC
                                                                     (SYSDATE,
                                                                      'yy'
                                                                     )
                                                             AND TRUNC
                                                                    (  SYSDATE
                                                                     - 1
                                                                    )
                                                     THEN TO_CHAR (sa.updat,
                                                                   'Mon dd'
                                                                  )
                                                  ELSE TO_CHAR (sa.updat,
                                                                'DD/MM/YYYY'
                                                               )
                                               END
                                              )
                                          ),
                                       '0000/00/00 00:00:00'
                                      )
                              FROM sfa_activity sa
                             WHERE sa.companyid = opp.companyid
                               AND sa.opptyid = opp.opptyid
                               AND sa.TYPE = 'NOTE')
                   ELSE (SELECT NVL
                                   (MAX
                                       (TO_CHAR
                                           (CASE
                                               WHEN TRUNC (sa.updat) =
                                                               TRUNC (SYSDATE)
                                                  THEN TO_CHAR (sa.updat,
                                                                'hh12:mi PM'
                                                               )
                                               WHEN TRUNC (sa.updat)
                                                      BETWEEN TRUNC (SYSDATE,
                                                                     'yy'
                                                                    )
                                                          AND TRUNC (  SYSDATE
                                                                     - 1
                                                                    )
                                                  THEN TO_CHAR (sa.updat,
                                                                'Mon dd'
                                                               )
                                               ELSE TO_CHAR (sa.updat,
                                                             'DD/MM/YYYY'
                                                            )
                                            END
                                           )
                                       ),
                                    '0000/00/00 00:00:00'
                                   )
                           /*ELSE (SELECT (MAX(TO_CHAR(sa.updat,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')))*/
                         FROM   sfa_activity sa
                          WHERE sa.companyid = opp.companyid
                            AND sa.opptyid = opp.opptyid
                            AND sa.TYPE <> 'NOTE')
                END
               ) AS activity_made
          FROM sfa_opportunities opp
         WHERE companyid = 1192)
```